# Is there a name for the `2d 4h 30m` time period format from Youtrack and Jira?

Tags: time, format, jira, iso, youtrack

I saw this 1-letter time convention in a bunch of places, the most relatable one is when you specify time spent on a task in YouTrack:

[image]

But is there an official name for it? Like you know, how `P1DT12H` is an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

The YouTrack seems to refer to it just as "[Period Format](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Add-Work-Items-to-Issue.html#add-work-items-time-tracking-tab)", but that is too broad to use it out of context.

[image]

The reason I need this is that I have to pick a good name and specification link for a function that parses a string of this format, as our team chose it to represent durations in config files.

So far I'm going with the "*Lettered Duration*", but I wonder if there is a widely accepted name for this convention.

Related question: ['Human-readable' time short formats conventions?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/114640/human-readable-time-short-formats-conventions)

Comment: YouTrack uses [org.joda.time.Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) as a base class for period values. Hope this helps.